# org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat8, tomcat-dbcp

I recently installed a newer version of Eclipse (Neon v1) and Tomcat 8.0, and I am now getting this error:

> org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp cannot be resolved to a type.

I am 99% sure that nothing in my code has changed. The way I understand it, `org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp` comes from the JAR in Tomcat's library called "tomcat-dbcp.jar" which is there.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Tomcat and Eclipse, but I'm still getting the same error. I've tried adding the `tomcat-dbcp.jar` to my project libraries and tried importing it directly in the java file but I still get the error. I know it is something to do with the `.jar` files but I cannot figure out what else I can possibly do.

Answer (score 1):

Nevemrind, figured out that there is a new version of DBCP and I had to change the tag to "org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2" to fix the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "you had to change the tag?"
I am experiencing this issue I was hoping you could elaborate with your solution.
I know you might have forgotten about it but Im just trying, hoping you could still remember it

Thanks in Advance!